# PXSelect Statement Translation

Tags: c#, acumatica

I need the following SQL query translated into a PXSelect:

```
SELECT *
FROM APRegister r
WHERE r.UsrExceptionType = 'TAX'
```

I do not want to use an IN statement if there is another way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TAX needs to be defined as a constant first:

```
public class Tax : Constant<string> { public Tax() : base("TAX") { } }
```

I assume UsrExceptionType is a custom field that is part of a DAC extension. You'll have to use the DAC extension name to refer to the custom field. By default when generated by the customization project editor DAC extension should be named `APRegisterExt` but it could be anything if you manually created the DAC extension:

```
PXSelect<APRegister, Where<APRegisterExt.usrExceptionType, Equal<Tax>>>
```

BQL In operator is not a direct equivalent to SQL In operator. It has few use case and your approach to avoid it if not necessary is good.